# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I had already search for the solution but there were not working, I install the library through drag and drop the framework. I am not using the cocopods.

I am getting the duplicate symbol in following files:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter duplicate
>   symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter  duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter  duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter

There is total 194 files in which duplicate issue is occurring.

[image]

I think its because of Google Sign in Framework and Firebase Analytics framework. Can some one please help me

Comment: are you using cocoa pods ?

Comment: Please check framework is there any added twice?

Comment: @UmarFarooque No

Comment: @Jaydeep No framework is repeated, I just Google Framework for Sign in and Firebase analytics that may include some similar file

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Select your project target
**Step 2:** Go to build phases
**Step 3:** Search for your duplicate file, GTMLogStandardFormatter
**Step 4:** If you find two files in the same location, just remove one that your problem will be solved.